# FMDB: Does calling a method to make a query in the inDatabase block work the same way?

Tags: fmdb

I'm trying to remove some database records, and I have a wrapper class around my FMDB class. What I'm wondering, is if I can call this class method from the `inDatabase` block?

```
[_dbQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
    // Do some magic here to get 1234
    [myObject deleteWithId:1234]; // This calls executeUpdate:@"DELETE..."
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the latest FMDB, it should crash on you (if your other method is using inDatabase: as well).  Recursive inDatabase: calls aren't advised.

Comment: No, it isn't recursive. I'm making one inDatabase: call but inside that block, I'm calling myMethod which calls executeUpdate. This is different from the docs that say I should have the executeUpdate straight inside of the inDatabase: block. Would that still work?

Comment: You know what, I think I just realized that this may have been a silly question (and one that I shouldn't have thought about asking at 2am..)

Thanks!