# What's the correct way to use inDatabase: within an async networking call?

Tags: afnetworking, fmdb

I'm using AFNetworking along with FMDB to remove database rows from an array when I make a successful POST to a server. My problem at the moment is that my logging shows that I'm skipping every second item in the array, so I think I've incorrectly used FMDB in conjunction with AFNetworking's async request.

This is what the code looks like:

```
[manager POST:[_urlEndpoint absoluteString] parameters:data success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    [_dbQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfIds.count; ++i)
        {
            NSLog(@"Removing event at index: %@", arrayOfIds[i]);
            [_db removeWithId:arrayOfIds[i]];
        }
    }];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

In the `arrayOfIds`, the logs shows that I hit 1, skip 2, hit 3, skip 4, etc. In this particular case, I've made sure I'm only sending one POST request so narrow down the root cause so I know there aren't multiple accesses to `arrayOfIds`.

What could I have done wrong that I may have missed?

(Possibly) related question I just asked before: [FMDB: Does calling a method to make a query in the inDatabase block work the same way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719471/fmdb-does-calling-a-method-to-make-a-query-in-the-indatabase-block-work-the-sam)

**EDIT:** Here are what my logs look like..

```
2014-07-13 03:08:28.684 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Adding event to array to be sent: 1
2014-07-13 03:08:28.684 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Adding event to array to be sent: 2
2014-07-13 03:08:28.684 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Adding event to array to be sent: 3
2014-07-13 03:08:28.684 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Adding event to array to be sent: 4
2014-07-13 03:08:28.684 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Adding event to array to be sent: 5
2014-07-13 03:08:28.684 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Adding event to array to be sent: 6
2014-07-13 03:08:29.191 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] JSON: {
    description = "Server response from /events";
    name = response;
}
2014-07-13 03:08:29.192 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Removing event at index: 1
2014-07-13 03:08:29.192 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Removed event from row: 1
2014-07-13 03:08:29.195 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Removing event at index: 3
2014-07-13 03:08:29.195 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Removed event from row: 3
2014-07-13 03:08:29.196 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Removing event at index: 5
2014-07-13 03:08:29.197 PostTestApp[77268:6675567] Removed event from row: 5
```

- `"Adding event to array to be sent:"` is a for-loop that adds database IDs into `arrayOfIds`.
- `"Removing event at index:"` happens inside the `inDatabase:` block.
- `"Removed event from row:"` happens
  inside `removeWithId:`.

**EDIT 2:**

Full code block without edits: https://gist.github.com/jonalmeida/27bee72b9015d45434e8

Comment: I don't think it's an AFNetworking issue. AFNetworking completion blocks are all called on the main thread. What is `_db` and why not use `db`? Is `_db` a different `FMDatabase` than `db`? What logs are you talking about? Can you post their actual output?

Comment: `_db` is my wrapper class around the `FMDatabase`. It just does a `[FMDatabase open]` check before executing the DELETE query using `removeWithId:`.

I'll update the question with the logs, give me a sec.

Comment: Is the problem that your conditional is `i < arrayOfIds` instead of `i < arrayOfIds.count`?

Comment: It seems too consistent a problem for that to actually be the cause, so I'm assuming that's an effect of simplifying your code for this question.

Comment: No, it actually is arrayOfIds.count, I changed the variable names to make them easier to read. Fixed that now!

Comment: @AaronBrager yeah, I'm guessing it's just user error on my behalf. I just can't tell where... I've stared at this block for a while now.

Comment: It looks like either the adding code (not shown) is wrong (your array actually has 1, 3, 5, 7, etc.), or that the deleting has some effect on the ID array.

Comment: I've added the actual code in a gist on the post as well. It's a bit messy so I apologize for that.

The adding has to be correct since I can see from the logs that it is added correctly. If I run this code block again, it sends the remaining items then (in the same fashion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your gist, your actual code looks like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < dbIndexArray.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Removing event at index: %@", dbIndexArray[i]);
    [_db removeEventWithId:[[dbIndexArray objectAtIndex:i] longLongValue]];
    [dbIndexArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

The problem is: you are modifying the array while you're iterating through it. When you remove object 0, and object 1 becomes object 0.

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *removedIDs = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i=0; i < dbIndexArray.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Removing event at index: %@", dbIndexArray[i]);
    [_db removeEventWithId:[[dbIndexArray objectAtIndex:i] longLongValue]];
    [removedIDs addObject:dbIndexArray[i];
}

[dbIndexArray removeObjectsInArray:removedIDs];
```

Comment: Moral of the story: Go to sleep after 1am.. urgh! Thanks a lot Aaron!